# How to use SOCIAL_AUTH_PROCESS_EXCEPTIONS setting

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I am working on a website that supports Facebook association via django-socialauth. The library works great except when sometimes I need to deal with 'Account already in use' ValueError.

It appears from django-socialauth's [documentation](http://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) (search for 'exception') that SOCIAL_AUTH_PROCESS_EXCEPTIONS setting exists to specify an exception handler. So I created a dummy function:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PROCESS_EXCEPTIONS = 'myapp.utility.process_exceptions'
```

But when I initiate a ValueError, the handler never gets called. Does anyone have experience with using this key SOCIAL_AUTH_PROCESS_EXCEPTIONS before?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using django-socialauth or django-social-auth?

Comment: apologies, I am actually using django-social-auth==v0.6.6

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to modify the authentication pipeline and create your own version of this function, which is in social_auth/backend/pipelines/associate.py:

def associate_by_email(details, *args, **kwargs):
    """Return user entry with same email address as one returned on details."""
    email = details.get('email')

```
warn_setting('SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_BY_MAIL', 'associate_by_email')

if email and setting('SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_BY_MAIL', True):
    # try to associate accounts registered with the same email address,
    # only if it's a single object. AuthException is raised if multiple
    # objects are returned
    try:
        return {'user': User.objects.get(email=email)}
    except MultipleObjectsReturned:
        raise AuthException(kwargs['backend'], 'Not unique email address.')
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        pass
```

If you replace this line:
raise AuthException(kwargs['backend'], 'Not unique email address.')
for a pass statement, then if there are duplicate emails in the db (meaning it can't associate to any specific account), it will not attempt to associate by email and will instead pass to the next item in the pipeline. Ultimately this should lead to a new account being created.

Comment: This approach is a bit old as of today, Matías Aguirre, the developer of DSA points out. The middleware is the preferred method now. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-social-auth/_TlXWTV0RxI/2kEZQPws90UJ